# React js get children from object if name of object is equal with another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get children array from the object if object name is equal with another name.
The array is:

```
const testDataTwo = {
    name: 'level 1 - 111',
    date: 'level 1 - 222',
    children: [
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5551', b3: 'level 1 - 6661' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5552', b3: 'level 1 - 6662' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5553', b3: 'level 1 - 6663' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5554', b3: 'level 1 - 6664' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5555', b3: 'level 1 - 6665' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5556', b3: 'level 1 - 6666' }
    ]
  }
```

```
// This is for old question
const testData = [
  {
    name: 'level 1 - 111',
    date: 'level 1 - 222',
    children: [
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5551', b3: 'level 1 - 6661' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5552', b3: 'level 1 - 6662' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5553', b3: 'level 1 - 6663' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5554', b3: 'level 1 - 6664' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5555', b3: 'level 1 - 6665' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5556', b3: 'level 1 - 6666' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'level 2 - 111',
    date: 'level 2 - 222',
    children: [
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5551', b3: 'level 2 - 6661' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5552', b3: 'level 2 - 6662' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5553', b3: 'level 2 - 6663' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5554', b3: 'level 2 - 6664' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5555', b3: 'level 2 - 6665' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5556', b3: 'level 2 - 6666' }
    ]
  }
];

const selectedObject = ["level 1 - 111"]
```

I tried with map method to loop on the array but I am not getting any result

```
console.log(testData.map((item) => (item.name === selectedObject ? item.child : '')));
```

`selectedObject` can have more than one name like this: `const selectedObject = ["level 1 - 111", "level 2 - 111"]` and in that case should be logged two objects.

Comment: what is your expected output (can you add an example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.reduce` will be more apt here in this case. Because `Array.map` will return a response for each node of the input array. That will be not good for showing undefined values.

Use `Array.reduce` with `Array.some` to check if the name is present in a list of names.

```js
const testData = [
  {
    name: 'level 1 - 111',
    date: 'level 1 - 222',
    children: [
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5551', b3: 'level 1 - 6661' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5552', b3: 'level 1 - 6662' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5553', b3: 'level 1 - 6663' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5554', b3: 'level 1 - 6664' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5555', b3: 'level 1 - 6665' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5556', b3: 'level 1 - 6666' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'level 2 - 111',
    date: 'level 2 - 222',
    children: [
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5551', b3: 'level 2 - 6661' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5552', b3: 'level 2 - 6662' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5553', b3: 'level 2 - 6663' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5554', b3: 'level 2 - 6664' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5555', b3: 'level 2 - 6665' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5556', b3: 'level 2 - 6666' }
    ]
  }
];

const selectedObject = ["level 1 - 111"];
const response = testData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (selectedObject.some((node) => node === curr.name)) {
    acc.push(curr.children);
  }
  return acc
}, []);
console.log(response);
```

**Edit**

If the testData is an Object, there is no need for a looping logic. You could simply check whether its name is included in the array using `Array.some` or `Array.includes`

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const testDataTwo = {
  name: 'level 1 - 111',
  date: 'level 1 - 222',
  children: [
    { a3: 'level 1 - 5551', b3: 'level 1 - 6661' },
    { a3: 'level 1 - 5552', b3: 'level 1 - 6662' },
    { a3: 'level 1 - 5553', b3: 'level 1 - 6663' },
    { a3: 'level 1 - 5554', b3: 'level 1 - 6664' },
    { a3: 'level 1 - 5555', b3: 'level 1 - 6665' },
    { a3: 'level 1 - 5556', b3: 'level 1 - 6666' }
  ]
};
const selectedObject = ["level 1 - 111"];
const response = [];
if (selectedObject.some((node) => node === testDataTwo.name)) {
  response.push(testDataTwo.children);
}
console.log(response);
```

Comment: hi @Nitheesh. Thnaks for your answer. I would like to get your idea about what if testData would be an object like testDataTwo (I updated my question)

Comment: @alar If the testData is an Object, there is no need for a looping logic. You could simply check whether its name is included in the array using `Array.some` or `Array.includes`

Comment: Why this answer was downvoted without specifying a reason?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) you can check for at least one match. This should then work when having multiple selected objects:

```
console.log(testData.map((item) => (selectedObject.some((obj => obj === item.name)) ? item.children : '')))
```

---

As per Nick Parsons comment, Using includes results in the same output:

```
testData.map((item) => (selectedObject.includes(item.name) ? item.children : ''))
```

Comment: `selectedObject.includes(item.name)` might be a simpler implementation instead of `.some()`

Comment: yes you are right that would be easier. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You ought to add the index to the selectObject[0] while using it because it's an array

```
console.log(testData.map((item) => (item.name === selectedObject[0] ? 
item.children : '')));
```

And also it should be `item.children`

Comment: `selectedObject` can have more than one string in it, this will only work for the first string

Comment: I think he's only testing a value at the moment, so I think that answers his question

Comment: they do specifically state: _"`selectedObject` can have more than one name like this: `const selectedObject = ["level 1 - 111", "level 2 - 111"]` and in that case should be logged two objects"_, so I personally feel as though that's a requirement that should be considered

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions guys. Yes, selectedObject can have more than one strings and can't use selectedObject[0]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over `testData`. Instead run your loop over `SelectedObject` array so you get a corresponding value for all items. You cant then use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get your required array item from `testData`.

```js
const testData = [
  {
    name: 'level 1 - 111',
    date: 'level 1 - 222',
    children: [
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5551', b3: 'level 1 - 6661' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5552', b3: 'level 1 - 6662' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5553', b3: 'level 1 - 6663' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5554', b3: 'level 1 - 6664' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5555', b3: 'level 1 - 6665' },
      { a3: 'level 1 - 5556', b3: 'level 1 - 6666' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'level 2 - 111',
    date: 'level 2 - 222',
    children: [
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5551', b3: 'level 2 - 6661' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5552', b3: 'level 2 - 6662' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5553', b3: 'level 2 - 6663' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5554', b3: 'level 2 - 6664' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5555', b3: 'level 2 - 6665' },
      { a3: 'level 2 - 5556', b3: 'level 2 - 6666' }
    ]
  }
  ]
  
  
  const selectedObject = ["level 1 - 111", "level 2 - 111"]

let ans = [];
selectedObject.forEach((x) => {
let foundItem = testData.find( a => a.name === x);
if(foundItem!== undefined){
ans.push(foundItem.children);
}
});

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) those objects where the object name is [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) in the `selectedObject` array, and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over that array and return the children.

```js
const testData=[{name: 'level 0 - 111', date: 'level 0 - 222', children: [{a3: 'level 0 - 5551', b3: 'level 0 - 6661'},{a3: 'level 0 - 5552', b3: 'level 0 - 6662'},{a3: 'level 0 - 5553', b3: 'level 0 - 6663'},{a3: 'level 0 - 5554', b3: 'level 0 - 6664'},{a3: 'level 0 - 5555', b3: 'level 0 - 6665'},{a3: 'level 0 - 5556', b3: 'level 0 - 6666'}]},{name: 'level 1 - 111', date: 'level 1 - 222', children: [{a3: 'level 1 - 5551', b3: 'level 1 - 6661'},{a3: 'level 1 - 5552', b3: 'level 1 - 6662'},{a3: 'level 1 - 5553', b3: 'level 1 - 6663'},{a3: 'level 1 - 5554', b3: 'level 1 - 6664'},{a3: 'level 1 - 5555', b3: 'level 1 - 6665'},{a3: 'level 1 - 5556', b3: 'level 1 - 6666'}]},{name: 'level 2 - 111', date: 'level 2 - 222', children: [{a3: 'level 2 - 5551', b3: 'level 2 - 6661'},{a3: 'level 2 - 5552', b3: 'level 2 - 6662'},{a3: 'level 2 - 5553', b3: 'level 2 - 6663'},{a3: 'level 2 - 5554', b3: 'level 2 - 6664'},{a3: 'level 2 - 5555', b3: 'level 2 - 6665'},{a3: 'level 2 - 5556', b3: 'level 2 - 6666'}]},{name: 'level 3 - 111', date: 'level 3 - 222', children: [{a3: 'level 3 - 5551', b3: 'level 3 - 6661'},{a3: 'level 3 - 5552', b3: 'level 3 - 6662'},{a3: 'level 3 - 5553', b3: 'level 3 - 6663'},{a3: 'level 3 - 5554', b3: 'level 3 - 6664'},{a3: 'level 3 - 5555', b3: 'level 3 - 6665'},{a3: 'level 3 - 5556', b3: 'level 3 - 6666'}]}];
const selectedObject = ["level 1 - 111", "level 3 - 111"];

const result = testData
  .filter(obj => selectedObject.includes(obj.name))
  .map(obj => obj.children)
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getLevelsByName(selectedObject, testData) {
  const result = [];

  for (let item of selectedObject) {
    const objectFound = testData.find((c) => c.name == item);
    if (objectFound) {
      result.push(objectFound); // you can push objectFound.children if you only want children of object
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(getLevelsByName(selectedObject, testData));  //logs selected objects
```

Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-7sa9im